# Ruby slim inline if

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, inline, slim-lang

I'm trying to do an inline `if` with Ruby Slim.

Given my example below...

```
- if @droppable
  .panel data-draggable="true"
    span More content here
- else
  .panel
    span More content here
```

In both cases, the only difference is the presence of the `data-draggable` attribute on the top-level `.panel` element. The contents of the `.panel` is identical, so I'd like to accomplish something like the following:

```
.panel (@droppable ? data-draggable="true")
  span More content here
```

Is there a way of achieving this in Slim?

Comment: the first example is correct. you may have problem with @droppable . try to print it in the page and check its value.

Comment: “doesn't work” is an inappropriate error report. Please provide an exact error message and the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry for my "doesn't work", I mean the "span hello" is only visible if @droppable isn't true. I don't know how to  show the span hello for both case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for an `if` here, and the ternary operator requires three operands, not two.

Both Slim and HAML are designed to omit attributes with nil/false values, intentionally letting you use the `&&` operator to turn a truthy/falsy value to the *presence* of attribute with a specific value, or its absence:

In Slim:

```
.panel data-draggable=(@droppable && "true")
  span Hello
```

In HAML:

```
.panel{data: {draggable: @droppable && "true"}}
  %span Hello
```

In both cases, if `@droppable` is a truthy value, `data-draggable="true"` will be added, otherwise the attribute will be omitted.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Dynamic tags is _way_ overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use [dynamic tags](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#dynamic-tags-):

```
ruby:
  def panel!
    {tag: 'panel'}.tap do |tag|
      tag[:"data-draggable"] = true if @droppable
    end
  end

*panel!
  span hello
```

Comment: Slightly overkill to achieve a simple optional attribute

Comment: Yes, but “give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.”

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an **"inline if"** , but you can get the behavior you want with  [slim in line html support](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Inline_html__)
doing this:

```
<div class="cool_class"       
  - if conditional_is_met
    | data="must_be_added"
    | special_data="#{@my_data.to_json}" 
  |          
</div>
```

consider that inside the html tag the slim identation is still followed.
and the final `|` is important to close the if.